# Javascript merge and replace value by key on 2 array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge, lodash

I'd like to merge 2 arrays of objects in Javascript, the source array is something like:

```
padding = [{'t': 1, 'c': 0}, {'t': 2, 'c': 0}, {'t': 3, 'c': 0}]
data = [{'t': 3, 'c': 5}]
```

The result should look like:

```
result = [{'t': 1, 'c': 0}, {'t': 2, 'c': 0}, {'t': 3, 'c': 3}]
```

Please note that `data` is being populated into `padding` by matching `'t'`. I've tried various method, such as jQuery `$.extend({}, padding, data)`, however it doesn't output correctly.

Appreciate if you share something. Thanks.

Edit 1 (10 April 2020)

As @codemaniac pointed out, I had a typo, the result should be:

```
result = [{'t': 1, 'c': 0}, {'t': 2, 'c': 0}, {'t': 3, 'c': 5}]
```

Additional (10 April 2020)

I have `padding` length of 1000, for `data`, it should be the subset of `padding` by the key `'t'`.

I am looking for **efficient** way of "merging" and "replacing" the `data` into `padding`, some call it "addition", given that `padding` will always padded with `'c': 0` for every object.

I don't mind to try out `lodash` JS utility if it's possible.

Comment: how come it become `{'t': 3, 'c': 3}` ?

Comment: How did you achieve the final result? Please example the problem properly :)

Comment: @CodeManiac I've corrected as you mentioned.

Comment: @YousufKhan I've made a typo in the original post, I have added an edit to the post.

Comment: ok and what will be the final result if `data = [{'t': 4, 'c': 5}]` and `padding = [{'t': 1, 'c': 0}, {'t': 2, 'c': 0}, {'t': 3, 'c': 0}]`?

Comment: @CheeHow i've posted an answer, see if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want an addition, to get the proper size of your element (padding + width)

```js
const padding = [{
  t: 1,
  c: 0,
}, {
  t: 2,
  c: 0,
}, {
  t: 3,
  c: 0,
}];

const data = [{
  t: 3,
  c: 5,
}];

// Use a reduce to build the new array
function mergeData(d1, d2) {
  return d2.reduce((tmp, x) => {
    // Check if the array already contains the key 't'
    const found = tmp.find(y => y.t === x.t);

    // If it does, add 'c' together
    if (found) {
      found.c += x.c;
    } else {
      // else, add the missing entry
      tmp.push(x);
    }

    return tmp;
  }, d1);
}

console.log(mergeData(data, padding));
```

Comment: Thanks. The result seems to be not sorted. The purpose of this question being that I want to align some randomly missing data points in “data” with “padding” by key “t” so that they appear uniform on a chart.

Comment: I use `mergeData(padding, data)` instead. I got it working by switching the parameters in `mergeData` method. Hence, accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to merge the arrays but also replace objects from `padding` with objects from `data` given the t value, this is one way:

```js
const padding = [{'t': 1, 'c': 0}, {'t': 2, 'c': 0}, {'t': 3, 'c': 0}];
const data = [{'t': 3, 'c': 5}, {'t': 5, 'c': 6}];

const merged = [];

// loops through the objects in padding. If it finds an object in data that has the same t value, it chooses the object from data to add to the merged array. Otherwise, it uses the object from padding

padding.forEach((obj) => {
  let dataObj = data.find(dataObj => dataObj.t === obj.t);
 if (dataObj) {
  merged.push(dataObj);
 } else {
  merged.push(obj);
 }
});

// loops through the data array. If there are any objects in data with a t value not in any padding object, it adds this to the merged array

data.forEach((obj) => {
 let paddingObj = padding.find(paddingObj => obj.t === paddingObj.t);
 if (!paddingObj) {
  merged.push(obj);
 }
});

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: Thanks for going extra mile. I guess I don’t need the “data” loop. I’d like to check the performance, I think optimisation will be needed. “data” should be subset of “padding”, but looping thru “padding” seems wasteful...the actual length of “padding” is 1000

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map` and `map`

- First use Map to build a Map Object from data with `t` as key and `c` as value
- Now loop over padding array and see if `t` is present is Map we use value of `c` from Map and else from current element only

```js
const padding = [{'t': 1, 'c': 0}, {'t': 2, 'c': 0}, {'t': 3, 'c': 0}];
const data = [{'t': 3, 'c': 5}];

const mapper = new Map(data.map(( { t, c } ) => [t, c] ));

const final = padding.map(({ t, c }) => ({
    t,
    c: mapper.has(t) ? mapper.get(t) : c
}));

console.log(final);
```

Comment: If I change all format into array, wouldn't it be simpler? `padding = [[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0]]` and `data = [[3, 5]]` to get `result = [[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 5]]`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about efficiency but this piece of code works and is pretty readable

```
var padding = [{'t': 1, 'c': 0}, {'t': 2, 'c': 0}, {'t': 3, 'c': 0}]
var data = [{'t': 3, 'c': 5}, {'t': 4, 'c': 5}]

data.forEach(d => {
    padding.find(p => p.t === d.t).c = d.c
})

console.log(padding)
// OUTPUT: [ { t: 1, c: 0 }, { t: 2, c: 0 }, { t: 3, c: 5 } ]
```